# In the proof of the first order necessary condition for a local minimum what is the reason for the last step?

Tags: calculus

The proof is in this [lecture](https://youtu.be/tnOOiSjTI8I?list=PL6EA0722B99332589&t=1753).

Here is a reprint.

---

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. $f \in C^1$.
Consider the problem, $\min_{x \in R} f(x)$.

- Result (First Order Necessary Condition)

If $x^*$ is a local minimum of $f$, then $f'(x^*) = 0$

- Proof.

Suppose $f'(x^*) > 0$. $f \in C^1 \Rightarrow f' \in C^0$.

Let $D = (x^* - \delta, x^* + \delta)$ be chosen such that $f'(x) > 0 \space \forall x \in D$.
Therefore, for any $x \in D$ using first order truncated Taylor series,

$$f(x) = f(x^*) + f'(\bar x)(x - x^*) \text{ where } \bar x \in (x^*,x)$$

Choosing $x \in (x^* - \delta, x^*)$ we get,

$$f(x) < f(x^*) \text{, a contradiction.}$$

Similarly, we can show $f(x) < f(x^*) \text{ if } f(x^*) < 0$.

---

Towards the [end of the segment](https://youtu.be/tnOOiSjTI8I?list=PL6EA0722B99332589&t=1980) he notes that $f'(\bar x)$ is positive and $\bar x - x$ is negative and then immediately jumps to showing that $f(x) < f(x^*)$ which is a contradiction. To me he is saying that $f(x) = f(x^*) - \text{some negative number}$. How is $f(x) < f(x^*)$ following from that?

**Edit**: I just noticed that $\bar x \in (x^*, x)$ and $x \in (x^* - \delta, x^*)$. That makes $\bar x = \emptyset$.

Does it follow from that $f'(\bar x)(x - x^*) = 0$ since $\bar x = \emptyset$? Is that how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$f(x) = f(x^*) + \textrm{some negative number}$$
then,
$$f(x) - f(x^*) = \textrm{some negative number}$$
therefore,
$$f(x) - f(x^*) < 0$$
thus,
$$f(x) < f(x^*)$$

Comment: Oh, lol. What about the $\bar x$ being the empty set?

Comment: $(x^*, x)$ can only be empty if $x = x^*$, but $x \in (x^* - \delta, x^*)$ which is an open interval.

Comment: So in $(a,b)$ it does not have to be that $a < b$?

Comment: Yes, typically, a should be less than b. However, take it as a slight abuse of notation in this case.